# How to make oat milk that is not chalky

Tags: oat-milk

I'm making oat milk like this:

Put 4 tbsp around 40 grams **Rolled Oats** (without soaking) into blender, then add 1 cup (300 mL) **Cold water**, then add **1 tbsp canola oil** (to help emulsify). Then I blend them. Then I filter is using a cloth.

The result is thin and chalky.

Now how to make the oat milk less chalky? I couldn't find any discussion about this online.

Comment: We have https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/105905/my-oat-milk-is-too-watery?rq=1. I'm not entirely sure we should consider it a duplicate, since you focused on the chalk part of homemade oat milk and the other asker on the thinness, but yes, that's what homemade oat milk is like - raw starch swimming in water.

Comment: Yea I want to ask about the "chalkiness"... I read that emulsifier such as xanthan gum or lecithin can emulsify / homogenize the water & non-water particle. I think I'm going to buy xanthan gum soon. If anyone has any experience please let me know

Comment: Tell us more about your equipment & process. What kind of blender are you using? A high speed blender like a Vitamix or Ninja will give different results from a standard Oster bar blender or a handheld stick blender. How long do you blend? How fine is the cloth you're straining through?

Comment: I am using ordinary blender, it's Indonesian brand, costs somewhere 15-30 USD. Not as fancy as Vitamix. I basically use hotel laundry bag [like this] (https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FThe-Laundress-Hotel-Laundry-Bag%2Fdp%2FB000OR207U&psig=AOvVaw3Z2NDjHx8VcOS9n1TAMM0r&ust=1587042059792000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJC4j8S-6ugCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE) yea I'm using anything I have at home to keep costs down :)

Comment: I'd suggest editing your original question with those details. I think they will be valuable to getting a definitive answer. I *think* the lower power/speed blender is the cause. But I don't have experience to offer that as much more than a guess... And don't have any alternatives.

Comment: I'm using a high power blender (Nutribullet) and having the same problem. Did you friend a solution @BrianIvanderT.P. ?